# Can you create a navigation based table that links to multiple detailview controllers on the ipad

Tags: ipad, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

Is there a way of designing an app with the following structure. I have tried so many tutorials, but none of them do what I am trying. I wonder if it is because it cannot be done.

I want a SplitViewController, with the Masterview having a Tableview that has multiple items in it. Each item pushes to a new Masterview table that has the items which can then be selected.

If an item is chosen in the first sub menu, it opens up DetailViewController1 and displays the relavent information.

If an item is chosen in a separate submenu item, it opens up DetailViewController2 and displays the information.

I have looked at Apple's MultipleDetailView Controller tutorial, but it is designed for only a single level MasterViewController table. Can I put a navigationcontroller in the MasterDetailController and then still get the pushing to new detailviewcontrollers?

In the AppDelegate, you choose the subviews, so how would you keep changing the subviews depending on the selection?

I also tried with using storyboards and got a partial solution using segue's that use the style"Replace". I found I could have a navigation based MasterViewController, and it pushed to new detailviewControllers, but I couldnt get the popovercontroller to work right. I couldnt get the toolbar to appear and give me the button to reappear the MasterViewController.

Hope it was clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me using the Master Detail template with storyboards on iOS 6. I'm using Xcode 4.6.2

1. Modify the code of the MasterViewController to eliminate the stuff you don't need and then create a subclass of it, eg. SubviewMasterViewController or whatever name you choose.
2. Drag a tableview controller to your storyboard and connect it to your current Master view controller with a segue (tableview to tableview, NOT from cell to tableview). Change the identifier of its cell to a name different from the cell of the Master view controller in the Attributes Inspector.
3. Give the segue a unique name for its identifier, eg. showSublevel.
4. Assign the tableview controller that you connected to your Master view controller to use that subclass that you just created in the Attributes Inspector.
5. Go back to your MasterViewController.m file. In the

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method, use the performSegueWithIdentifier:sender method to navigate to the tableview controller that you added.
6. In the SubMasterViewController.m file, change the implementation of the

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method, specifically the line UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath] by setting the cell identifier to that the cell of your new tableview controller.
7. Also change the name of the UITableViewCell *cell of that line to something else like UITableViewCell *cellular instead, otherwise Xcode will throw a hissy fit.
8. Repeat steps 2-7 for each tableview controller that you add to the Master view controller. Make sure that you use unique names for the cell identifiers of each tableview controller.